# Qt::Sheet and QMessageBox::show() on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmessagebox

I have an application where I want to ask the user a question in a `QMessageBox` and then respond accordingly. The problem is that on a Mac I want the dialog to show up as a Sheet, but using the `open()` method returns immediately.

```
QMessageBox* msgBox = new QMessageBox(
    QMessageBox::Question,
    "Delete Record?",
    "Are you sure you want to delete this record?"
    QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No,
    this,
    Qt::Sheet);

int ret = msgBox->exec(); // does not show up as a sheet on Mac
msgBox->open(); // shows up as a sheet but returns immediately
```

Is there anyway I can get which button the user pressed on a sheet without having to implement my own `QDialog`? Is there any signal from `msgBox` I connect?

Answer (score 5):

The document [recommends](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum) using `setWindowModality()` instead. The following code works for me:

```
auto m = new QMessageBox(&window);
m->setText("some text here");
m->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
m->exec();
```

Comment: But exec() would make it "application modal", that is, no other windows of the app could receive events.  If you really want to receive events in other windows, then since a QMessageBox is a QDialog, you could connect to signals of QDialog and then call open().

Answer (score 0):

This is PyQt sample from my application, but you'll get the idea:

```
reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Delete',
            "Are you sure?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes |
                QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
         #some action if YES clicked
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but this doesn't answer my question. Using the static method question() shows a modal dialog on Mac (as it does on Windows) and I want to show a Sheet.